# add SPListItem to a SPListItemCollection

Tags: development, asp.net

I have the following code to load a list from SharePoint site.

All is working well except a `SPList` item to `SPListItemCollection`.

```
 private void Data_load()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();


            string currentName = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name;
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Editor'/><Value Type='Person or Group'>" + currentName + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://spdev-6/"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList lists = web.GetList("Lists/Advertisements");

                    SPListItemCollection items = lists.GetItems(query);

                    if (items.Count > 0)
                    {
                        DataRow dr=null;
                        SPListItemCollection ITEM = null;
                        foreach(SPListItem item in items)
                        {
                            string A = item["Approval Status"].ToString();
                            if(A== "2")
                            {
                                ITEM.Add(item);

                            }


                        }
                        if(dt.Rows.Count==0)
                            lbldata.Text = "No data to show";

                      //  dt = items.GetDataTable();


                    }
                    else
                        lbldata.Text = "No data to show";



                    GridViewD.DataSource = dt;
                    GridViewD.DataBind();
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["Advertisement"] = dt;


                }
            }

        }

Now in if(A== "2"){ ITEM.Add(item); }
```

I want to add `SPListItem` to a `SPListItemCollection`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `ITEM.Add(item);` isn't it working?

Comment: `SPListItemCollection ITEM = null;` what is this? You never assign this a value this and then you do an `.Add` on it. That will surely throw a `NullReferenceException`.  Not sure what you are really trying to achive?

Comment: Atish its not working

Comment: Robert initially there is nothing to assign ITEM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First its a bit difficult to understand the code. However I am assuming below

1. You are getting all the items in `items` object.
2. Now based on the `Approval Status` you are creating a new `SPListItemCollection` object.
3. Lastly you get all the filtered items in DataTable and bind to a gridview.

**There can be 2 things which you can look at**:

1. Instead of filtering items after you get all of them, why not add a `clause` in your `CAML` query. This will bring a nice filtered data which needs not any processing and can be directly bind to Gridview.
2. You are calling `Add(item)` method on object of `SPListItemCollection`. But according to the list of [`members of SPListItemCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollection_members.aspx), there is overload of `Add` which contains single parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful to anyone else.
I had a SPListItemCollection, but from that I needed a subset of the values (I did not modify the query as I needed all the values initially, then a small subset).  I was looping through the collection as you did, but because you cannot add an SPListItem to a Collection, I simply created a List of type SPListItem and added each item to the list followed by continue.  I could then iterate through that list as needed.

```
    List<SPListItem> subList = new List<SPListItem>();
    foreach (SPListItem item in ColItem) {
      string parentID = Convert.ToString(item["ParentID"]);
      if (parentID != "0" && parentID != "")
                            {
                                subList.Add(item);
                                continue;
                            }
                            REST OF MY CODE
```